# ImportError: No module named impyla

Tags: python, hadoop, thrift, impala

I have installed impyla and it's dependencies following [this](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla) guide. The installation seems to be successful as now I can see the folder **"impyla-0.13.8-py2.7.egg"** in the Anaconda folder (64-bit Anaconda 4.1.1 version).

But when I import impyla in python, I get the following error:

```
>>> import impyla
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named impyla
```

**I have installed 64-bit Python 2.7.12**

**Can any body please explain me why I am facing this error?** I am new on Python and have been spending allot of time on different blogs, but I don't see much information present there yet. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Type `which python` and tell me what you see

Comment: I get this error:

>>> which python
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    which python
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Amir He means type `which python` in terminal :)

Comment: my mistake, I get this on terminal, 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Amir try `python -V` instead

Comment: It shows me, "Python 2.7.12"

Comment: ok so I googled and found that "which" is a Unix command. The equivalent command for windows is "where". After entering "where python", I get 2 paths to python.exe. One path is to python.exe present in the anaconda folder and the other to the Python27 folder. Both pythons are of the same version!

Comment: maybe try to install python 32bit edition. then try using impyla lib again..

Comment: Yes i am going to do that, will update you soon :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage is a little bit different then you mentioned (from https://github.com/cloudera/impyla)

Impyla implements the Python DB API v2.0 (PEP 249) database interface (refer to it for API details):

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='my.host.com', port=21050)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100')
print cursor.description  # prints the result set's schema
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

The Cursor object also exposes the iterator interface, which is buffered (controlled by cursor.arraysize):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100')
for row in cursor:
    process(row)
```

You can also get back a pandas DataFrame object

```
from impala.util import as_pandas
df = as_pandas(cur)
# carry df through scikit-learn, for example
```

Comment: Yes I know about this. This should work but first I have the issue of import :P Will be updating you shortly :)

Comment: you should import impala! not impyla. impyla is the lib name and using for pytest usage such as:  py.test --connect impyla

Comment: Oh you are so TRUE. It works now, after getting Python2 32-bit, I can import impala now. Thanks :)

Comment: can I also connect to Hive in a similar way as well? any thoughts about it!

Comment: yes I guess so. you can try those also: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHive/0.2.1